# Using fsolve in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I want to use `fsolve` to find the 2 values of a function `z(q)` in which I know the value of q (q_1000)

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

k_b   = 1.38064852e-23 
n_0   = 2e+25          
m     = 4.8e-26        
g     = 9.81           
T     = 300            
I_inf = 400            
sigma = 4e-22          
kappa = 0.2            

H     = (k_b*T)/(m*g) 

val   = 100
z_min = 1e+5
z_max = 4e+5
z     = np.linspace(z_min, z_max, val)

# ______________________________ Functions ___________________________________________

n = lambda z : n_0*np.exp(-z/H)                
I = lambda z : I_inf*(np.exp(-(sigma*n(z)*H))) 
q = lambda z : kappa*sigma*n(z)*I(z)           

q_max   = q(z).argmax()    # q_max
q_1000  = q(z)[q_max]/1000 # q_max / 1000
result1 = fsolve(q,q_1000) # start at z = q_1000

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.title('z(q)')
plt.axis([1e-11, 1e-1, 1e+5, 4e+5])
plt.plot(q(z)[q_max], z[q_max],'x', label="z*=q_max", color="red")
plt.plot (q(z),z,'k-')
plt.plot(result1,q_1000,'ro')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('q')
plt.ylabel('z')
plt.show()

print(q(z)[q_max])
print(q_1000)
print(result1)
```

That's my result

[image: What I have]

That's what I want, with the 2 points (let's say Z1 and Z2)
[image: What I want]

Comment: Include imports in your code.  I have added some of them.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that's also "scipy.optimize"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to `fsolve` should be a function for which the roots `q(z) = 0` are sought. Therefore, `q(z) = q_1000` should be written as `q(z) - q_1000`. The second parameter to `fsolve` is an approximation to the desired root. I'm not sure how to get a good initial value in general, but in this case the plot suggests 1.5e5 and 2.5-e5.

In code, including the plotting:

```py
z1 = fsolve(lambda z: q(z) - q_1000,1.5e5)[0]
z2 = fsolve(lambda z: q(z) - q_1000,2.5e5)[0]

plt.plot((q_1000, q_1000), (z1, z2), linestyle='dashed', color='dodgerblue', label='z*=q_1000')
plt.plot(q_1000, z1,'ro')
plt.plot(q_1000, z2,'ro')
```

[image: the resulting plot]